# am I understanding MVVM correctly?

Tags: design-patterns, android, mvvm, android-development

- ViewModel has Two-way data binding with UI which means UI can access the data from ViewModel and can update the view models data.
- The Model has one-way data binding and is only supposed to respond back with the result that ViewModel requests.

am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Though the other question is worded differently, it got currently two excellent answers (especially the highest voted one, not the accepted one) which should answer this question in-depth.

Answer (score 1):

Your definitions are correct.

I wouldn't really say that a couple of textbook definitions is the same as "understanding" a design pattern though; that comes from using it in practice, and most importantly learning when it is the right design pattern to use, and when you should use a different design pattern.